# How to add drop down Table in to table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, drop-down-menu

In my application, I want to implement a drop down view when selecting every row in the table view.Can u give me an easy solution for implementing this functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this..http://stackoverflow.com/a/34586224/3908884

Answer (score 3):

this type of functionality  for that visits following link Please [visit here.](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/20/447/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using navigation. That is how it is usually done in iPhone. On selecting a row in a table, push another table with the values you want to show in the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a sample code of TableView which deals with this issue. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139  is the link to download the sample code from Apple developer library. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are requiring a popover on selecting a tableview cell.

Download and run the sample application provided [here](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover).

I hope this is the one you required.