# Make switch on a Tableview cell, open new lines on tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uiswitch, uitableview

I have a table view with one prototype cell where it have an switch and i need when i click on it, it opens a new line for user input a information like de reminder app. See images below

[image: before click]

[image: after click]

How can i add theses new lines on my table using swift??

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33187198/3882338

Make 2 different cells and reload the table view accordingly.